# Fetching field values from uncommitted features on Qgis

Tags: qgis, features, qgis-plugins, layers, c++

I'm trying to fetch a feature's field value on Qgis, I use 
 `QgsFeature.attributeMap().value(cont int & key).toDouble()` 
This works fine for committed features but it always returns " 0 " if the feature is not yet committed to the vector layer !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm iterating over the layer's features to get a specific feature with :

`pQgsVlayer->select( attributeList, pQgsVlayer->extent() ); 

QgsFeature tFeature; 

while ( pQgsVlayer->nextFeature(tFeature) ){ 

.. 

}`

Here, attributes are fetched to the QgsFeature resulting from `nextFeature(..)` !

The problem was that I get the feature's Id from this iteration then I use it to get to the feature when needed with :

`pQgsVlayer->featureAtId(id, Feature);`

uncommitted attributes are, then, not fetched !

I solved this by using to iteration to get the feature itself not the id, so it will have all of its attributes when I use it !

Answer (score 1):

QgsFeature is just temporary entity that is returned from the layer or the provider.  QgsFeature doesn't "know" where the data originated from.

I suppose you're fetching directly from the provider, but to get the uncommitted changes you must fetch the feature from the layer.